# How to find total number of products under each category using mysql joins?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - catgories and products. I want to get total number of products falling under each category? My tables look as:

table **categories**

```
category_id     category_name
1               first category
2               second category
3               third category
```

table **products**

```
product_id     product_name     category_id
1              first product    1
2              second product   1
3              third product    1
4              fourth product   3
5              fifth product    3
```

I want following output:

```
category_id     category_name     total_products
1               first category    3
2               second category   0
3               third category    2
```

I am currently using following sql but it is not yielding me correct result:

```
SELECT `c`.`category_id`, `c`.`category_name`, COUNT(`p`.`product_id`) AS total_products FROM `categories` AS `c` INNER JOIN `products` AS `p` ON `c`.`category_id` = `p`.`product_id` GROUP BY `p`.`category_id`
```

Comment: Shouldn't your JOIN clause be `ON c.category_id = p.category_id` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use left join as

```
select
c.*, coalesce(count(p.category_id),0) as total_products
from categories c
left join products p on p.category_id = c.category_id
group by c.category_id ;
```

Comment: Coalesce isn't actually necessary here, but I see where you're coming from

Comment: my problem has fixed by changing code to above comment by @Patrick Fournier

Comment: Are you sure `inner join` lists out 0 count as well ?